# Can I define Data Domain for an attribute in a table in MySql

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

How can I define data domain for an attribute in mysql table.
For example I want 'male' or 'female' values in gender attribute of student table not any other than these. Is it possible in mysql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible, use **`ENUM`** data-type.

An `ENUM` is a string object with a value chosen from a list of permitted values that are enumerated explicitly in the column specification at table creation time.

e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE shirts (
    name VARCHAR(40),
    size ENUM('x-small', 'small', 'medium', 'large', 'x-large')
);
```

For more information [look here.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/enum.html)